# How do you blitzmax IDE on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I just installed Ubuntu and wanted to install everything I have on my windows. I use this programming ide called blitzmax and I need to know how to install it.

It is not like installing for windows, I just need a basic tutorial on how to install any application without using the software center.

Comment: Presumably you checked the manufacturers web site?

Comment: What format is it? Is it .exe?

Comment: You may find this helpful. http://blitzmax-ide.sourceforge.net/ or perhaps this: http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=71505

Comment: Tutorial: http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=97927

Comment: you need to find the specific file for it's installation on linux distributions and for what programming language you need it?? and have a look at this <http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=97927>